# React Route not navigating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have written below routes in App.js -

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    
   <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard} ></Route>
      <Route path="/details/:index" exact component={ItemDetails} ></Route>
      <Dashboard></Dashboard>
      </Switch>
     
     </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have another component - Items which has Card (Reactstrap). Each card is having a Link -

```
function Items(props) {
    console.log(props.index.index)
    return (
        <Link to={{pathname:"/details",param1:props.index.index}}>
        <Card tag="a" key={props.index.index} style={{display:'flex',width:'25%',flexWrap:'nowrap',float:'left',cursor: "pointer"}} 
          >
        <CardBody>
            <CardTitle> {props.card.card.value} </CardTitle>
        </CardBody>
    </Card>
    </Link>
    )
}

export default Items
```

Within Link tag , to attribute , I have mentioned -

```
to={{pathname:"/details",param1:props.index.index}}
```

By this I am expecting , upon clicking of card , component - `ItemDetails` should get rendered.
But I cannot see , ItemDetails has got rendered.

Do I need to add anything else within my current code ?

Comment: Maybe try to append the index to the pathname string: <Link to={{pathname:"/details" + props.index.index}}>

Comment: to={{pathname:"/details/" + props.index.index}} @TobiasS. this did worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `useHistory` hook which solve this problem easily

```
import React from 'react'
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
function Items({index, card}) {

    const history = useHistory()

    function navigateTo(){
        history.push(`/details/${index.index}`)
    }

    return (
 
        <Card onClick={navigateTo} tag="a" key={props.index.index} style={{display:'flex',width:'25%',flexWrap:'nowrap',float:'left',cursor: "pointer"}} 
          >
        <CardBody>
            <CardTitle> {card.card.value} </CardTitle>
        </CardBody>
    </Card>
    )
}
export default Items
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add exact attribute to your "/" route. And  component is given in Route not in Switch block

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    
   <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" exact component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path="/details/:index" exact component={ItemDetails} />
    </Switch>
     
     </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may change the path param with Template literals

```
<Link to={`/details/${param1:props.index.index}`}></Link>
```

Complete code is something like this

```js
  function Items(props) {
    return (
        <Link to={`/details/${param1:props.index.index}`}>
        <Card tag="a" key={props.index.index} style={{display:'flex',width:'25%',flexWrap:'nowrap',float:'left',cursor: "pointer"}} 
          >
        <CardBody>
            <CardTitle> {props.card.card.value} </CardTitle>
        </CardBody>
    </Card>
    </Link>
    )
}
export default Items
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NavLink` and change the `Card` tag from `a` to something else. Otherwise you will have nested `a` tags.

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
function Items(props) {

const linkTo = `/details/${props.index.index}`;
return (
    <NavLink to={linkTo}>
    <Card tag="span" key={props.index.index} style={{display:'flex',width:'25%',flexWrap:'nowrap',float:'left',cursor: "pointer"}} 
      >
    <CardBody>
        <CardTitle> {props.card.card.value} </CardTitle>
    </CardBody>
</Card>
</NavLink>
)
}
```